# Dot Product for 3rd order and 2nd order Tensor

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

If I had a tensor of rank **3** and another tensor of rank **2**, what will their dot product be? Also, how could I represent the process with indices, please explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider a 3rd order tensor $\boldsymbol T$ and a 2nd order tensor $\boldsymbol U$. The dot product $\boldsymbol V = \boldsymbol T \cdot \boldsymbol U$ is a tensor of rank $3+2-2 = 3$. If we express the coordinates $V_{ijk}$ of $\boldsymbol V$ on an orthonormal basis using the Einstein summation convention, we have
$$
V_{ijk} = T_{ijl}\, U_{lk} \, ,
$$
where $T_{ijl}$ and $U_{lk}$ are the coordinates of $\boldsymbol T$ and $\boldsymbol U$, respectively.
The summation is performed along the last index of the coordinates of $\boldsymbol T$, and the first index of the coordinates of $\boldsymbol U$.

Comment: Could you please provide any reference for studying dot product and other operations on higher order(>2) tensors?

Comment: @AakashGupta There are many, and it may depend on your purpose. You may have a look to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#General), and references therein.